# Check if objectID exists in coredata

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am pretty new to iOS development, currently my coredata is in a corrupted state. In my application I have a coredata Object of type `A` which holds reference to another coredata Object of type `B`.

Due to some bug, there are some `A` objects which are referring to `B` objects which are removed from coredata. So when I am trying set something on `A.B` object, the app crashes because it trying to load `B` from coredata and faults.

So I tried to add a check before accessing the object to see if the object actually exists in the coredata, If it does not exist I am trying to create a new object.

This is my implementation for checking the existence of object :

```
- (BOOL)hasObjectWithObjectID:(NSManagedObjectID *)objectID {
       NSManagedObject *managedObject = nil;
       if (objectID) {
          NSError *error = nil;
          managedObject = [self.managedObjectContext existingObjectWithID:objectID error:&error];
          if (error) {
               ERROR(@"Could not fetch persistent model with id : %@ , error : %@", objectID, error);
          }
       }
    return managedObject != nil;
  }
```

I was expecting this method to just return `nil`, whenever I am trying to run this on a reference which does not exist in coredata, I get the following error :

```
error : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133000 "The operation
couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 133000.)".....
```

But according to docs `existingObjectWithID` does not throw any error when the reference does not exist

`/* returns the object for the specified ID if it is already registered in the context, or faults the object into the context.  It might perform I/O if the data is uncached.  If the object cannot be fetched, or does not exist, or cannot be faulted, it returns nil.  Unlike -objectWithID: it never returns a fault.  */`

How do I handle this situation? Is this the correct way to check if the object exists in the coredata?

**UPDATE** : I expected to get `nil` when accessing the property of A which points to B, but it returns an object with data as Fault and it crashes when trying to actually setting some value to it.

**If I print `A.B`, I get the following :**

`(entity: B; id: 0xd000000002380012 <x-coredata://2AC34EF0-A808-4460-86C1-86470F6767D6/B/p142> ; data: <fault>)`

I confirmed that there is no object with id 142 of type B in coredata.

Strangely this crashes only on **iOS 8**, on higher versions of iOS with the same coredata the app doesn't crash.

Comment: As per the documentation, it returns `nil` if the object doesn't exist. But you should be able to just check the reference property of `A` that refers to `B`. It will be `nil` if there is no referenced object

Comment: Make sure that your delete rule is "nullify"and not "no action"

Comment: @Paulw11 Yeah, I thought that's how it should work but in my case, it was returning an object with data as `Fault`. I updated the question with the details.

Comment: If it returns a fault then the object exists. As soon as you refer to a property of the faulted object then the data will be read from disk.

Comment: If you have invalid references then you need to make sure your delete rule is “nullify” and then reset your core data and you should be right from then on

Comment: @Paulw11 unfortunately resetting  coredata is not option in my case. So I just wanted to see if I can check the object existence and if the object does not exists, fix the references by creating a new object of type B and set it to A.

Comment: The you are back to my first comment. If `existingObjectWithID` returns `nil` then the object doesn’t exist. If it returns a fault then the object does exist

Comment: ah, now I understand what you mean. But any Idea when I would see the `Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133000` in case of `existingObjectWithID `?

Comment: It means that the fault refers to an object that doesn’t exist. https://osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=133000